# Read JSON multi-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, json

I have an issue I haven't been able to find a solution to, because it's not quite straight forward I guess...

In my Java program, I receive a string like this (from an existing source, I can't change it, sadly):

`["a", 1, "b", 2, ["c", "d", 3], 4]`

This string is a valid JSON array (no object, so no key/value pairs!). The content of the array may be totally random (for instance, empty) but can also be multi-dimensional.

I need to find a way to read this in Java. For instance, `input.get(4).get(2)` should give me `3` in the above example. I don't really care if everything is casted to a string, but I need to find a way to reach the data through indices. Data may also be multiple characters, although my example shows only 1 per element.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Edit; I do know how many elements I expect in the root array, but there are a few dozen cases so I really don't want to program something different for each case

Comment: Can you not use a [JSON library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)?

Comment: @univerio The problem is that this JSON array is totally random, so I don't think that will work, I tried but did not yet succeed.. If you can show me how, that would be great!

Comment: @univerio I tried a lot.., I tried to parse it myself but got stuck on recursion and making sure every 'inner' array closes before continuing, I tried to use several JSON libraries but they depend on static structure of the JSON array, or that the JSON array only consists of the same type (e.g. not Strings, Integers and Arrays mixed).. If you know anything, please help..

Comment: Any of the JSON parsing libraries available (the only exception being to horrid simple json thing) will parse this JSON, and provide you with an array of Java objects.

Comment: There are over a dozen JSON toolkits for Java.  See json.org for about half of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick a JSON library. *Any* of them.

The basic `org.json`:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourString); 
JSONArray arrayTwo = array.getJSONArray(4); 
int i = arrayTwo.getInt(2);
```

Gson:

```
JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(json);
JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
JsonArray arrayTwo = array.get(4).getAsJsonArray();
int i = arrayTwo.get(2).getAsInt();
```

Etc, etc.

Comment: I saw I never picked an answer here. Thanks for taking the time back in 2014 to explain the concept of libraries to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using jackson 2.3.0:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree("[\"a\", 1, \"b\", 2, [\"c\", \"d\", 3], 4]");
int i = node.path(4).path(2).intValue();
System.out.println(i);
```

prints

```
3
```

Javadoc for `JsonNode` is [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html).